# How does a hash digest update function work?

Tags: node.js, hash, cryptography, updates, digest

When creating a hash digest, in most libraries you have the option to update the input an arbitrary number of times with new inputs before computing the final digest.

For example:

```
hash = new Hash('sha-256');
hash.update('some text');
hash.update('additional input');
finalOutput = hash.digest();
```

**How does the update actually affect the input? Is the implementation dependant on the library?**

**For some context,** I am using the *crypto* library in *NodeJS* and want to test the output of a function using a *SHA-256 hash*. To generate the output, I am calling the update function several times, and I want to be able to generate the same output in some online calculator in order to have an expected value to compare my actual output to.

Comment: I've added an alternative answer to the question marked as dupe, comment below if you've got any related questions or if it somehow doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there someway I can construct an initial input that is equivalent to two inputs (initial and one passed through .update)? So for example, can I construct an initial input that is equivalent to the algorithm as `hash.update("Hello"); hash.update("World");` perhaps through padding or some other means?

Comment: Ok by inspection, the Node implementation seems to treat the following as equivalent: `hash1.update("HelloWorld");` and `hash2.update("Hello"); hash2.update("World");` after a `digest` call is made on both `hash1` and `hash2`

Comment: Correct, yes. The hash will be completely identical to hashing the concatenation of all the data in the update methods. It is just there so you can feed the data piecemeal, in  case it is not completely available at once. In other words, you can *stream* the data into it using multiple calls.